# accessing the 'this' keyword in a react functional component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand how make a component that can remove itself from a array of components with functional components. Here is the sample code of what I'm trying to do:

```
const App = () => {
    <ObjState>
        <ObjectCreator />
        <ObjectList />
    </ObjState>
}

const ObjContext = createContext();

const ObjReducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
    switch(type) {
        case Types.ADD_OBJ:
            return {
                ...state,
                objects: [...state.objects, payload]
            };
        case Types.REMOVE_OBJ:
            return {
                ...state,
                objects: state.objects.filter(obj => obj !== payload)
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const ObjState = ({ children }) => {
    const initialState = {
        objects: []
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ObjRecuder, initialState);

    const addObj = (obj) => {
        dispatch({
            type: Types.ADD_OBJ,
            payload: obj
        });
    }

    const removeObj = (obj) => {
        dispatch({
            type: Types.REMOVE_OBJ,
            payload: obj
        });
    }

    return (
        <ObjContext.Provider value={{
            objects: state.objects,
            addObj,
            removeObj
        }}>
            {children}
        </ObjContext.Provider>
    );
}

const ObjCreator = () => {
  const { addObject } = useContext(ObjContext);
  const createObj =() => {
    const obj = (<ObjectTypeA key={uuid()} />);
    addObject(obj);
  }
  return (<button onClick={createObj}>create an object!</button>)
}

const ObjectList = () => {
  const { objects } = useContext(ObjContext)
  return (
    <fragment>
      {objects}
    </fragment>
  )
}

const ObjectTypeA = ({ key }) => {
  const { removeObj } = useContext(ObjContext);
  const removeSelf = () => {
      removeObj(this);
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={removeSelf}>remove me!</button>
  )
}
```

The problem is you can't reference `this` in the final `Object` component.
I have the unique key but I'm not sure how to pass it through correctly. I attempted to build a reducer action that took the `key` from the `Object` and removed it that way but `key` came back as `undefined` even though it is deconstructed out of the props and I'm using an arrow function to preserve it.

I feel like I'm tackling this problem in the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

I think you veer off-course when trying to store what looks to be React components in your context state, you should be storing objects instead. The objects should have unique GUIDs. This allows the reducer to identify which object element to remove from state. The `ObjectList` should then render derived React components from the stored state.

> I attempted to build a reducer action that took the key from the
> Object and removed it that way but key came back as undefined even
> though it is deconstructed out of the props and I'm using an arrow
> function to preserve it.

This is because React keys (and refs) are not actually props. Keys can't be accessed in children components. You can can pass the same value via just about any other named prop though. Note below in solution I pass a React key ***and*** an `id` prop.

## Solution

ObjectCreator: Creates objects, not React components

```
const ObjectCreator = () => {
  const { addObj } = useContext(ObjContext);
  const createObj = () => {
    const obj = {
      id: uuid()
    };
    addObj(obj);
  };
  return <button onClick={createObj}>create an object!</button>;
};
```

SpecificObject: passes its `id` to the `removeObj` callback.

```
const MyObject = ({ id }) => {
  const { removeObj } = useContext(ObjContext);
  const removeSelf = () => {
    removeObj(id);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={removeSelf}>remove {id}</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

ObjectList: renders the context `objects` mapped to JSX.

```
const ObjectList = () => {
  const { objects } = useContext(ObjContext);
  return (
    <>
      {objects.map((el) => (
        <MyObject key={el.id} id={el.id} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Check the passed `id` payload in the remove object reducer

```
const ObjReducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case Types.ADD_OBJ:
      return {
        ...state,
        objects: [...state.objects, payload]
      };
    case Types.REMOVE_OBJ:
      return {
        ...state,
        objects: state.objects.filter((obj) => obj.id !== payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit accessing-the-this-keyword-in-a-react-functional-component]

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with the id / key thing, I didn't realize they would strip access to the prop. but there is nothing wrong with an array of JSX objects in the state as far as I can tell, they are objects like any other.

Comment: It's possible to put all kinds of javascript types in the state, but I would not recommend it. It's common practice to only use json data in state. It makes it easier to understand, test and debug.

Comment: The problem is I need the array to contain different components with specific callbacks and functionality.

Comment: Instead of putting that in the state, this could be done using hooks in the component that needs that functionality. useCallback can be used for callback functions. You can use useRef for any other non-serializable type.

Comment: @JakeBlackwell If it was just a plain JSX literal I think I might be able to agree with you on storing them in state, but you are trying to store an instantiated React component, which is basically a snapshot of that component from that render cycle. As soon as you try to do any "React-y" things like access/update state things tend to get a little weird due to javascript enclosures. You can store "dynamic" data in state, including the component type to be rendered, and when mapping the data you simply lookup what component the data should be rendered into.

Comment: @JakeBlackwell See [Choosing the Type at Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime). The specific component handles getting the correct callbacks they need, as Haken points out.

Comment: This last bit is exactly my problem. Like I'd said at the beginning, I'm going about this the wrong way. Thanks again!