# Cannot read property 'insertOnMatch' of undefined - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm using TypeScript to create a match/player module in mongoose.
I create this `insertOnMatch` function to use the mongoose `findOneAndUpdate` function adding the player to my match schema, but I'm recieving a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` while trying to update that document in mongo

Full error code:

```
(node:508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertOnMatch' of undefined
```

`insertOnMatch` function

```
  private async insertOnMatch (matchId: String, playerId: String): Promise<void> {
    await Match.findOneAndUpdate({ matchId: matchId }, { $push: { matchPlayers: { playerId: playerId, playerRefererMatchId: matchId } } })
  }
```

`create` function

```
public async create (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    const newPlayerConfig = {
      playerId: generatedPlayerId,
      playerMatchRefererId: req.params.matchId
    }

    const newPlayer = await Player.create(newPlayerConfig)

    this.insertOnMatch(newPlayer.playerMatchRefererId, newPlayer.playerId).catch(err => { console.error(err) })

    return res.json(newPlayer)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you try to call `insertOnMatch` on a functional component using **this**. And it is undefined as there's no class instance. [accessing the 'this' keyword in a react functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66325017/accessing-the-this-keyword-in-a-react-functional-component)