# event handler is undefind and it won't recongize -React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and I'm super confused why this event handler is undefind ?

```
const Login = () => {
  
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("Clicked");
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type="email" />
      <input type="password" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

i get `handleSubmit is not defined` error and i have no idea
why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a function component, let alone, using an arrow function. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66325017/accessing-the-this-keyword-in-a-react-functional-component) question for more details on that.

This means you don’t have access to the keyword “this”, which you’re using on your `onSubmit`!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have forgot **const** and you don't need **this** keyword because you are using function component

```js
const Login = () => {
  
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("Clicked");
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="email" />
      <input type="password" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up [the two different ways](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-functional-components-and-class-components-in-react/) to declare a React component.

Choose either:

1. **Class component**: which needs to extend the React.Component class, requires the return to be wrapped in `render`, and does need `this` to reference the class methods.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Clicked");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="email" />
        <input type="password" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

2. **Function component**: which is just a function, doesn't require `render`, and doesn't require you to reference `this` to call the handler functions. In addition, function components allow you [access to React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

```js
const { Component } = React;

function Example() {

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Clicked");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="email" />
      <input type="password" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```